# Raising a number to a power using only addition

Tags: c#, addition

I am trying to raise a number to a power using only addition but it does not work, it just raises a number bigger than the original.Here is my code:

```
private void ExpOperation()
    {
        result = 0;
        num01 = Int32.Parse(inpu01.Text);
        num02 = Int32.Parse(inpu02.Text);
        int a = num02;
        num02 = num01;
        int i = 1;


        while (i <= a)
        {
            result = SimpleMulti(num01,num02);
            num01 = result;
            i++;
        }
        result_Text.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    private int SimpleMulti (int num1, int num2)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int i = 1;
        while (i <= num2)
        {
            c += num1;
            i++;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: you need better naming convention, i cannot tell which is your exponent based on your code

Answer (score 0):

```
private int SimpleMulti (int x, int y)
{
    int product = 0; //result of multiply

    for (int i = 0; i<y; i++){
       product += x;
    } 
    //multiplication is repeated addition of x, repeated y times
    //the initial solution with a while loop looks correct 

    return product;
}

private int ExpOperation(int x, int exponent)
{
    int result = 1; 

    if (exponent == 0) {
      return result; //anything that powers to 0 is 1
    }
    else 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < exponent; i++){
            result = SimpleMulti(result, x);
            //loop through exponent, multiply result by initial number, x
            //e.g. 2^1 = 2, 2^2 = result of 2^1 x 2, 2^3 = result of 2^2 x 2
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Keep in mind that this method does not support negative exponent, which deals with division, but instead of using SimpleMulti, you can create a method for SimpleDivide which uses subtraction instead. The principle is the same

Comment: Please provide description to your answer. It will help others understand how your solution works.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this question is quite relevant to the main reason of this site, however I got a solution:

```
public long ExpOperation(int a, int b)
{
    long result = 0;
    long temp = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= b; i++) // Executes a full loop when we have successfully multiplied the base number "a" by itself
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= a; j++) // Increase the result by itself for a times to multiply the result by itself
            result += temp;
        temp = result:
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **x^y = x * x^(y-1)**, it can be solved recursively. Since `SimpleMulti` in question returns integer, I assume both base and exponent are non-negative integer.

```
private static int PowerWithAddition(int x, int y)
{
    if(y == 0){
        return 1;
    }

    var y1 = PowerWithAddition(x, y - 1);
    var sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < y1; i++)
    {
        sum += x;
    }

    return sum;
}
```